# Making the Name of the App appear in the Menubar (top-left corner) when the App is LSUIElement

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How would I make the name of the app appear here ( like with a normal app )…

[alt text http://snapplr.com/snap/6sgc](http://snapplr.com/snap/6sgc)

… when the app is an LSUIElement.

My Problem is that when the App is LSUIElement the name is not by default displayed in the menu bar like an normal app. Basically all I want LSUIElement to do is to hide the dock icon not the name in the menu bar.

For those who's native language isn't English, when I say 'App' i mean 'Application'.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do this; it's not what users expect.  A dock icon and menu bar go together.  If you want to get both a dock icon and menu bar icon in your UIElement app, use [TransformProcessType](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Carbon/reference/Process_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/TransformProcessType).

If you really must, you can draw your own menu bar window (if you use the appropriate window level it'll appear over the top of the existing menu bar).

Comment: How would I draw my own menu bar window?

Comment: Create an unadorned window starting to the right of the Apple menu and start drawing in it.  If you want the menu bar to look like the OS X menu bar, see the Appearance Manager documentation and HITheme.h.  You can get the menubar height and other such measurements with GetThemeMetric, then use functions like HIThemeDrawMenuBarBackground and HIThemeDrawMenuTitle to draw backgrounds; HIThemeGetUIFontType, HIThemeDrawTextBox and the like to draw text.  You can probably get away with using standard menus assuming you can either fix or disregard the rounded top corners on 10.5.